# Append to Text File VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I need to take values from a selected range to a comma delimited text file and append them. The code below gives me an error at Set TS. Why??

```
Sub Wri()

Dim myrng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myrng = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If myrng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No cells selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

Dim fs, f, TS, s
Dim cellv As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CreateTextFile "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt"
Set f = fs.GetFile("C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt")
Set TS = f.OpenTextFile(myrng.Value, 8, True, 0)

For Each Cell In myrng
    cellv = Cell.Value
    TS.Write (cellv & Chr(44))
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ive made you a custom sub, replace the sub with these two - the last param determins if it is an append or not and it will handle the new lines too :D

```
Sub writeCSV(ByVal thisRange As Range, ByVal filePath As String, Optional ByVal fileAppend As Boolean = False)
    Dim cLoop As Long, rLoop As Long
    Dim ff As Long, strRow As String

    ff = FreeFile
    If fileAppend Then
        Open filePath For Append As #ff
    Else
        Open filePath For Output As #ff
    End If

    For rLoop = 1 To thisRange.Rows.Count
        strRow = ""
        For cLoop = 1 To thisRange.Columns.Count
            If cLoop > 1 Then strRow = strRow & ","
            strRow = strRow & thisRange.Cells(rLoop, cLoop).Value
        Next 'cLoop
        Print #ff, strRow
    Next 'rLoop

    Close #ff
End Sub

Sub Wri()

Dim myrng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myrng = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If myrng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No cells selected"
    Exit Sub
Else
    writeCSV myrng, "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt", True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working!! One tiny issue though, if I select a range vertically, it adds the values vertically and if I select a horizontal range it adds values horizontally. Can the output be restricted to horizontal placement for either case??

Comment: Sorry, I cant replicate that.  Could you give me an example "vertical range"

Comment: If i select cells by dragging vertically, say from A1 to A7, the values are placed vertically in the text file(take up 7 lines), If I select cells by dragging say from A1 to E1, they appear horizontally(take up 1 line)

Comment: ah right, now Im with you - you want ONLY one row or column?

Comment: I'd like the output to be only in rows, irrespective of how the range is selected. One row followed by a line break every time the macro runs.

Comment: right, Ive made a "writeList" function instead of "writeCSV" below, give it a try :)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
Sub Wri()

Dim myrng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myrng = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If myrng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No cells selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

Dim fs, f, TS, s
Dim cellv As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CreateTextFile "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt"
Set TS = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt", 8, True, 0)

For Each Cell In myrng
    cellv = Cell.Value
    TS.Write (cellv & Chr(44))
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: With Set TS=f.., "Runtime error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method"
With Set TS=fs.., "Runtime error 13, Type mismatch"

Comment: I think you need to remove
"Set f = fs.GetFile("C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt")"
and change Set TS=f. to Set TS=fs.

Comment: Done, Set TS = fs.OpenTextFile(myrng.Value, 8, True, 0) has an error saying Type mismatch

Comment: woops, what should myrng.Value be?


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Worked!!! Thanks! But, If I run the macro twice, it overwrites values instead of appending, how can that be fixed?

Comment: Also, how do I add a line break in the end?

Comment: It shouldnt as you have opened for append (I'll look in a bit)

New line use a TS.Write vbNewLine

Comment: It does not append yet.

Answer (score 1):

to add all data to a "list"

```
Sub writeList(ByVal thisRange As Range, ByVal filePath As String, Optional ByVal fileAppend As Boolean = False)
    Dim cLoop As Long, rLoop As Long
    Dim ff As Long, strRow As String
    Dim tCell As Range
    ff = FreeFile
    If fileAppend Then
        Open filePath For Append As #ff
    Else
        Open filePath For Output As #ff
    End If
    For Each tCell In thisRange
        Print #1, tCell.Value
    Next tCell
    Close #ff
End Sub

Sub Wri()

Dim myrng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myrng = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If myrng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No cells selected"
    Exit Sub
Else
    writeList myrng, "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt", True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Its displaying vertically, need it to be horizontally! And you got rid of the comma delimiters, need those :p

Comment: Sorry, try the writeHList Ive added, should do it.

Answer (score 1):

ah right try changing the call writeList to writeHList then and use this sub:

```
Sub writeHList(ByVal thisRange As Range, ByVal filePath As String, Optional ByVal fileAppend As Boolean = False)
    Dim cLoop As Long, rLoop As Long
    Dim ff As Long, strRow As String
    Dim tCell As Range
    Dim strLine
    ff = FreeFile
    If fileAppend Then
        Open filePath For Append As #ff
    Else
        Open filePath For Output As #ff
    End If

    For Each tCell In thisRange
        If strLine = "" Then
            strLine = tCell.Value
        Else
            strLine = strLine & "," & tCell.Value
        End If
    Next tCell
    Print #1, tCell.Value
    Close #ff
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried it, still gives a vertical list without comma delimiters. I could work with the first custom sub but, problem pretty much solved :)

Comment: strange, works for me... although it does add the CR afterwards.  Would would need to change the line
   writeList myrng, "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt", True
to
   writeHList myrng, "C:\Users\HP\Documents\fil.txt", True

to use the new sub

Comment: There's one new problem, if I use merged cells(multiple rows merged as one), it gives me blank comma separated values for the remaining rows. How do I avoid this??

Comment: ooh, not sure - that would probably take some dev work (to ignore if >index0 of a merged cell range).  Im too involved in other work right now to look,  it might be worth a new question for someone to solve.