# Create a text file from data in a worksheet based on values in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet where i need to pull data from a columns based on other columns.  So if column **Filename** is SysInfoMgrServices.csv and column **7.4 J2** = "x" then i need the value in column **variable name** to be appended to a text document. See image. I would like it to loop through find all of the values in column B **variable name** if there is a corresponding value of "x" in column E **7.4 J2** and a corresponding value in column A **SysInfoMgrServices.csv** then insert into a text file. So if column 1 = SysInfoMgrServices.csv and column 2 = x bring back column 3 and insert into a text file. - Thanks

[image: example spread sheet]

Tried recording macros but not confident in will loop through worksheet.  Tried using filters.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. It would be useful for you to show us the code you have so far and explain what the exact problem with it is. FWIW, there are a lot of questions about looping through files on this site

Comment: [Example: Append to Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428667/append-to-text-file-vba) - [Example: Looping Through Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478474/loop-through-the-range-vba)

Comment: This may also be of use in comparing values AND writing to your text file. [Example: Use of dictionaries - write to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294634/write-vba-dictionary-to-text-file)